# Material Input Crops Input top and bottom

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have tried everything with CSS but nothing seems to fix this problem shown in the picture.
[image]

What's wrong with it and how can I fix it?

```
 <mat-form-field>
                <mat-label>إسم المستخدم</mat-label>

                <input matInput [(ngModel)]="username" autocomplete="off" name="username">
            </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: You can try to add a padding.

Comment: you can change the layout of form-field by adding ```appearance="legacy"```. This usually happens when you are using a custom font rather than the font provided by angular-material. Are you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same problem with Persian language and I fix it by adding `line-height` to the `input` element in `mat-form-field`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you've forgot to import `MatFormFieldModule` and `MatInputModule`
modules into your `app.module.ts` file.